# Does calling a member variable of constexpr struct omits a whole constructor evaluation?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

Let's say I have the following structure:

```
struct MyData {
    int minSteps{1};
    int maxSteps{64};
    double volume{0.25/7};
};

constexpr MyData data()
{
    return MyData();
}
```

Does any of expressions below make an instance of the MyData structure constructed somewhere before the value is assigned?

```
int steps = data().minSteps;
const int maxSteps = data().maxSteps;
constexpr double volume = data().volume;
```

Comment: All of these obviously create a `MyData` structure. That's what calling `data` does. Why would you think any of them *don't* create one?

Comment: I think OP means to ask whether the temporaries get would get optimized out or not, and to that I would say "yes, but check your [optimized] compiler output". Any reasonably optimizing compiler would have no reason to actually materialize those objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very unlikely an instance of `MyData` will actually be created if you compile your code with optimizations on. Any modern compiler should optimize it out. GCC will do so even at O0, MSVC will optimize it out at O1, so it's fair to say you likely don't need to worry about it if you don't intend to compile your code with optimizations completely turned off.

Take a look at it on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGISQCspK4AMngMmAByPgBGmMQSAGykAA6oCoRODB7evv5BaRmOAmER0SxxCVzJdpgOWUIETMQEOT5%2BgbaY9sUMjc0EpVGx8Um2TS1teZ0KE4PhwxWj1QCUtqhexMjsHLPEXg4A1ACyAJ4AIkxNhyYA7FYaAIKHL4fhBIcs4Y2YKQp3Fi4d3OJgAzA9nq93p8mKofn8AYlJMCwRDXod0BsYvRDgA3Tw%2BTAAjQAOjMAQA9LcUeCTE8aRC6Y80AxZphVCliCcLlcmBjeRAVkyAUz0cRMARNgxuZcmoLUcLbiD6U9oSwmOF5fT7qKoYJDmy/jdQed%2BXKViSvn0CL9/rSnuiWbM3vr1XCbUawab0AKLW74Xa0a8nTaOVzMV5sZg8QS2Mbvb6SfjckT7Y9gRw1rROAFeH4OFpSKhOG5rNYDRsttHzKCeKQCJpM2sANYgUGgkntrvdnvJbMcSR5xtFzi8BQgDT1xtrOCwJBoFgpOjxciUBdL%2BgJYBcMxcPh0G3EccQGLDmLhZqnTh1hdsQQAeQYtCvBd4WHVRnEr9I%2BHF9VxmDjt%2B7J1F4NrXrw7zdMOtB4DExCXh4WDDgQxB4CwEFrFQBjAAoABqeCYAA7veKSMBBMiCCIYjsFIlHyEoajDroe4GEYKBlpY%2BhweOkBrKgKS9EBAC096FrU9TOBArhTH4e6hAs5SVHohSZAIskqekakMEMSnLF0PQNHMGl7hJvT9C0ukjFU4wDCZtmWYp1kSGsCiVtseioZgOw8FmOZDt%2BxYcKoAAciTCUihzAMgyCHDuJJcIcEClpY1ikIcuCECQNxmLW6UeIuy5cjWXArLwDavisLZth2PZ1V2facIOpD5oWQVjhOU6VaQs6ICgqCFZuq4QOuRUgLiyApCkAD6uJcAAnNNBg2rM02qEi%2B60Iex6nt%2B57MMQL43gNd4EI%2Bz7Du%2BhjAF%2Bha/nUjgAUBhYgcgYE%2BZBgjQd%2BsHwYhGA7IWqHoZhfA4fhhEkWR%2BZ1vwVGiOIdFwwxKjqN%2BuhmPo10calXG/bxgpFoJWTjhS96md0D1ZC4DDuLGcnBLTVlLDZqm9PZbNZMzykU4ZAgWa09N6GZRkDNz%2BmzHZQumXM4tVK57m0fW4ofX5HC5i1w5BetkifAoE14gtJLLYBHzJZxNgZfgRDFble6HAVG7xDloJmGVXVaFVpCtu2nb1XV%2BhNQFbWjrYnUVZ7atmMHvDtR7TakABR7U5IQA%3D%3D%3D).

Comment: I completely agree this isn't something to worry about, but it is of note that in compiler explorer, MSVC is optimizing it out by just completely wiping the main method (except for returning 0) because the variables within it aren't used at all. Though you can see it does inline the constant values as expected if you declare the variables within main as `volatile` so they don't get optimized out completely.